# How to use REST API PdfReactor / MS Flow Post Request

Tags: pdf-reactor

I would like to convert a simple html file to PDF using PDF Reactor and MS Flow.

I set up a PdfReactor running in a docker container.

Can somebody help me to get the http post request right to have PdfReactor convert the file to pdf?

[image: Screenshot of the MS Flow I'm trying to build]

[PdfReactor Documentation](https://www.pdfreactor.com/product/doc_html/index.html#usingREST)

Comment: Hi JadDel! Can you share the http post request you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

The payload for most of POST methods of the PDFreactor Web Service must be in XML, JSON or ZIP format (see also https://www.pdfreactor.com/product/doc_html/index.html#payload).

So you should set the „body“ of your request to a JSON like the following:

```
{
    document: "Your File Content"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[NEW Flow HTTP Request Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VSlK.jpg)

With this request i was able to pass through the payload.

The content of the "html" Variable is going to look like this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Inspectionlist 0583 / 16.05.2020</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.Stil1 {
 font-size: 36px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.Stil11 {font-size: 44px}
.Stil12 {font-size: 36px}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="39%"><div align="center" class="Stil1">
      <p><span class="Stil11">I n s p e c t i o n s </span> <br>
  16.05.2020<br>
        </p>
      </div></td>
    <td width="32%"><div align="center"><span class="Stil11"><span class="Stil12">Ship-No.:</span> <span class="Stil1">0583</span></span> <br>
      </div></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table width="100%"  border="1" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#999999">
  <tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <th width="20" scope="col"><strong>No.</strong></th>
    <th width="70" scope="col"><strong>Start of insp. </strong></th>
    <th width="70" scope="col"><strong>End of insp. </strong></th>
    <th width="30" scope="col"><strong>Class.</strong></th>
    <th width="30" scope="col"><strong>Yard</strong></th>
    <th width="30" scope="col"><strong>Owner</strong></th>
    <th width="158" scope="col"><strong>Responsible</strong></th>
    <th width="30" scope="col"><div align="center"><strong>BGN</strong></div></th>
    <th width="481" scope="col"><strong>Description</strong></th>
    <th width="130" scope="col"><strong>Pre-Inspection Yard </strong><strong>Contractor</strong></th>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td width="20"><div align="center"><span class="Stil8"></span></div></td>
    <td width="70"><div align="center"><span class="Stil8"><B><FONT SIZE="6">No Inspections!<B></FONT> </span></div></td>
    <td width="70"><div align="center"><span class="Stil8"></span></div></td>
    <td width="30"><div align="center"><span class="Stil8"></span></div></td>
    <td width="30"><div align="center"><span class="Stil8"></span></div></td>
    <td width="30"><div align="center"><span class="Stil8"></span></div></td>
    <td><div align="center"><span class="Stil8"></span></div></td>
    <td width="30"><div align="center"><span class="Stil8"></span></div></td>
    <td><p align="left" class="Stil3 Stil6"><strong>No.</strong>  &nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Location:</strong>      <br><br>
      <br></p>
          </td>
    <td><div align="center"><span class="Stil8"><br>
    </span></div>      <div align="center"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<center> printed on: 15.05.2020 - 19:15 </center>
</body>
</html>
```

After the conversion the pdf is not readable by e.g acrobat, do you guys know what i'm missing?